# Laravel: cannot send notification to logged in user

Tags: laravel, email

I run into an issue with Laravel trying to send a notification to the logged in user.

I am running Laravel on top of Xampp.

My .env is set up like this:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=e577b5a0ea59d
MAIL_PASSWORD=320325e4b66352
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I have sent out mails to Mailtrap (to a fictitious email) and that works well.

Now I am trying to send a notification to the logged in user:

```
public function store() {
    Notification::send(request()->user(), new PaymentRecieved());
}
```

I get an error message:

```
Swift_TransportException
Cannot send message without a sender address
http://localhost/L6/public/payments
```

I am using the login methods that is included with Laravel/ui. My route looks like this:

```
Route::post('payments', "PaymentsController@store")->middleware('auth');
```

The authentication controllers I use are the one which are included with Laravel/ui.

I am getting the same error message when I am trying to use the reset password function.

I already tried all the advises about caches etc that I found, but none solves the problem.

Can anyone help?

Hubert

Comment: `Cannot send message without a sender address`, and `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null` ... There is one really obvious problem here, no? :-). And an obvious solution to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill in the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` and `MAIL_FROM_NAME` in your `.env` file, remember to clear cache via `php artisan cache:clear` afterwards.

Comment: The MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS did it. Stupid of me.

Comment: @Hubert1957 no worries! Stupid mistakes happen to the best of us! If this worked for you, consider marking my answer as correct for future generations :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the 'from' in app/config/mail.php

```
'from' => ['address' => 'myname@gmail.com', 'name' => 'myname']
```

and then

```
php artisan config:cache
```